# How to get the data from two DataGridViews into a third DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have one Form which has 3 DataGridViews. These DataGridviews are NOT DataBound. Shown Below are the Columns of the GridViews:

GridView01:

```
DPSNumber   DPSType StatusDateTime  CreatedBy   ChangedBy   CheckDuplicate
```

GridView02:

```
DPS #   Activity SubType    Group   Created By  Is Duplicate
```

I want to PROGRAMATICALY show the values from the two GridViews in the GridView03 as shown below:

GridView03:

```
DPSNumber   DPSType StatusDateTime  ActivitySubType Group   Created By
```

I want to use DPSNumber column of GridView01 as the Primary Column for GridView03 and LookUp the Values from GridView01 and GridView02 to populate the other columns.

I am using Visual Basic .net as the programming language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using datatables?

Create a datatable which combines both the gridviews and call it in third gridview.

Example:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable()
Dim dr as DataRow

                If dt.Columns.Count <= 0 Then
                    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("DPSNumber", GetType(UInteger)))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("DPSType", GetType([String])))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("StatusDateTime", GetType(UInteger)))
                    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("CreatedBy", GetType(UInteger)))
                     '... and so on

                End If

For i = 0 To GridView01.Rows.Count - 1
         dr = dt.NewRow()
         dr("DPSNumber") =  CheckNULLInt(GridView01.Rows(i).Item("DPSNumber"))
         dr("DPSType") =  CheckNULLInt(GridView01.Rows(i).Item("DPSType"))
         dt.Rows.Add(dr)
Next
```

Finally your third Gridview will be called as

```
GridView03.DataSource = dt
```

CheckNullInt Function

```
Public Function CheckNULLInt(ByVal value As Object) As Integer
        If Not IsDBNull(value) Then
            Return value
        Else
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function
```

Comment: @saadasharif:
GridView03.DataBind() does not work the intellisense shows me an error, "'databind' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'"
Moreover, it will be greatly helpful if you could elaborate the code for me by completing it (with just one or two columns only). So that I can paste it in my code any test it.

Comment: As the first comment states, DataBind cannot be used for DataGridView. Omit the last line and it should work fine. (I will elaborate the code shortly)

Comment: once again this piece, 'dr("DPSNumber") = CheckNULLInt(dgvGetData.Rows(i).Item("DPSNumber"))', is generating IntelliSense Error: "'Item' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView'"

Comment: Dude I have given you basic idea, you cannot expect your homework to be done here. It gives you enough of an idea to proceed further. I am inclined towards web development, so is my code. All you need to do now is "FOCUS" and sort it out.